# Bizspark Signup problems

Tags: bizspark

My company plainly meets the acquirements to enrol in Bizspark.  Yet so far I have not been able to.

I first applied via a Networking partner but heard nothing back and then discovered the Networking partner I picked did not have contact details on their website so I re-applied with a different live ID directly to Microsoft and again did not receive a response apart from the initial acknowledgement.

Waited a few weeks and then tried again picking another Networking partner. They graciously responded with a link to enrol.

Now a moth later I am about to give up.  I have a website (Although I dont yet need one as I have nothing to sell) and a working email address with the same domain.  Do the Bizspark team notify people if they have been declined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are you located ? It took me more than a month here (Australia) to get approval from a networking partner. You should contact more than 1 partner (if accepted by any, let the others know that you already get an approval) as the first partner didnt reply me and I had to try the second one.
I dont think they  will reply you if your application is declined.

Comment: Thanks Im in the UK. When the partner accepted you for enrolment did you again have to wait for MS approval or was that it? The partner Im dealing with sent me an enrolment code but I was informed I had to wait up to 5 business days for MS approval after i entered the code.